# android app testing in eclipse; location of ini file

Tags: android, eclipse, directory, ini

when trying to run a test of hello world html site in eclipse on a virtual android, I am getting a strange panic error message, that it can't find the relavant ini file for that virtual android.

I have found that such a file exists in Documents.android\avd folder.

the problem is that eclipse searches in a folder which seems impossible to create:

C:\Documents and Settings\user.android/avd/

I wanted to create such a folder and move the ini file there, but windows won't let me create a folder titled ".android".  What could I do?
Does eclipse have a setting for location of those ini files?

Comment: Not sure but i think its the problem due to spacing in the folder names (Document and Settings)

Comment: Try installing android sdk in some other location.

Comment: Hi Shashank the problem is that I can not find this folder choice in either eclipse or sdk toolkit. I have tried installing sdk to c:\android-sdk-windows\ and changed the reference in eclipse, but again, it has nothing to do with the placement of the avd file. Finally, I identified the actual location of the ini file with application found on everything.com and copied the ini file to the folder where eclipse wants it. Now it works! Maybe this will help someone in the future. Thank you.